# Where to find __sync_add_and_fetch_8?

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, atomic

I got errors when trying to use __sync_add_and_fetch:

```
test8.cpp:(.text+0x90e): undefined reference to `__sync_add_and_fetch_8'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Please kindly advise how to rectify this.

Specs:
GCC/G++: 4.4.1
GNU/Linux 2.6.32 SMP i686

Many thanks!

### EDIT:

In addition to the answer provided, one can use -march=i586 or -march=i686 to link successfully.

Note: This requires GCC/G++ 4.1.x and above!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That function is not supported on all x86 architectures. Try specifying your architecture, such as `--with-arch=pentium4`.